# Tools for creating Class Diagrams

Tags: class, diagram

Please suggest tools for creating Class Diagrams with the following criteria:

- It should be platform-independent because I use Linux and the file is expected to be edited by other members of the team using Windows/Mac
- Free, because there no such free tool, we should create one
- It would also be nice if you can include a screenshot of the class diagram produced, just to make sure that the tool is actually used for creating Class Diagrams and not just any other types of diagrams

Also, please only suggest the tools that you've actually used.

UPDATE: Please DO NOT include those UML Diagram tools that cannot create Class Diagrams.

Comment: why do you need platform independent? Do you work on all platforms?

Comment: I only work on Linux. But the diagram should also be editable by other members of the team using Windows/Mac.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737431/free-utility-which-runs-in-linux-to-create-a-uml-class-diagram-from-java-source-f among many others

Comment: UML is too generic for my need.  Some of those tools might be able to create UML Diagrams, but not Class Diagrams.

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify what you mean by "class diagram"? All UML tools that I've ever used can create class diagrams.

Comment: In two steps , we can create diagrams based on object/table relationships.
**Step 1:** use **DOT** (graph description language) to create graph representation of the relationships. 
**Step 2:** Use DOT reader libraries to render as picture.

Comment: A colleague of mine has just introduced me to www.draw.io.
Looks like it's what you guys are looking for. And free.

Comment: I second [www.draw.io](http://www.draw.io). The best tool out there in 2017

Comment: Recently introduced to draw.io and I recommend it.

Comment: Unlike GenMyModel, draw.io does not require registration, so +1

Comment: You can use https://github.com/knsv/mermaid

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I use [GenMyModel](http://www.genmymodel.com), first released in 2013. It's a real UML modeler, not a drawing tool. Your diagrams are UML-compliant, generate code and can be exported as UML/XMI files. It's web-based and free so it matches your criteria.

Comment: Experimenting it and it's really nice and clean! The login is pretty straight forward with g+ account. +1 for sure! :)

Comment: [GenMyModel](http://www.genmymodel.com/) - Awesome online tool, I strongly recommend!

Comment: its really clean and gets work done easily :) will love to promote `GenMyModel`

Comment: GenMyModel will no longer be free for private projects as of September 27, 2014

Comment: Nor is it free for public projects containing any more than 20 objects.

Comment: Nor can you export your diagrams (PDF, image, etc.) with a free account.

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot change the font style (I need a specific font, for the paper)

Answer (score 10):

I used [Poseidon UML Community Edition](http://www.gentleware.com/products.html), it's platform independent and makes fine and clean diagrams. There are some screenshots [here](http://www.gentleware.com/screenshots.html).

Comment: (+1) Great piece of software, and not a capsizing oceanliner in sight.

Comment: It seems that their downloads page was taken down, so here is the archive link for it: https://web.archive.org/web/20181102183143/http://www.gentleware.com:80/downloadcenter.html

Answer (score 9):

A nice online tool: [yUML](http://yuml.me/diagram/class/draw)

Answer (score 6):

Some time ago I used [DIA](http://live.gnome.org/Dia) - free and platform-independent. It was ok. Now I use [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/products/ea/index.html) but it's not free.

Answer (score 5):

I always use [Gliffy](https://www.gliffy.com/) works perfectly and does lots of things including class diagrams.

Comment: Guess the definition of free is lost on some people... This is not free, only free trial..

Answer (score 3):

[BOUML](http://www.bouml.fr/) is free, can reverse-engineer Java and C++

Answer (score 3):

Umbrello UML Modeller is a Unified Modelling Language diagram programme for KDE. UML allows you to create diagrams of software and other systems in a standard format. Our handbook gives a good introduction to Umbrello and UML modelling.  http://uml.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

Just discovered GenMyModel, an awesome UML modeler to design [class diagram online](http://www.genmymodel.com)

Comment: Only 20 elements in free version. Cannot have a private diagram

Comment: [ArgoUML](https://sourceforge.net/projects/argouml/), this is useful but the project has been [shutdown 4 years ago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArgoUML)

It's quite Consistent with Generation of Java Code from UML.

Answer (score 2):

I use [StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/). It works quite good.

Comment: I dislike starUML because it is not at all user friendly.

Comment: starUML has horrible UX and I've seen at least 5 bugs in the first minute...

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/) in the past - not free, but not too expensive, and it produces nice diagrams.

Answer (score 1):

I have used both [Poseidon UML](http://gentleware.com/products.html) and [Enterprise Architect](http://sparxsystems.com.au) and must say that I prefer Poseidon but wasn't fully satisfied with any of them.

Answer (score 0):

Since all these tools lack a validation function their outcomes are just drawings and no better tool for creating nice drawings is a piece of paper and pen. Afterwards you can scan your diagrams and insert them into your team's wiki.

Comment: Enterprise Architect does include validation, and is a modeling tool, not a diagramming tool.

Comment: One of the prerequisits was "Free, because there no such free tool, we should create one"

Comment: Something like Yuml.me turns a few lines of text into a better drawing than I can make, and best of all is re-editable. Spare a thought for those of us who are artistically challenged :)

Answer (score 0):

WhiteStarUML is a fork of StarUML that is still maintain http://sourceforge.net/projects/whitestaruml/?source=dlp.